# How to show and expand only one frame in tkinter frame swapping?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Both frames show when using pack(). The login frame is supposed to show first, and when register is clicked, the register email frame is supposed to show.

Works fine when using grid(), but the frame doesn't fill the container. I tried doing sticky on all four corners, but it only sticks to one corner.
The size of the container might not be the problem since I made sure it expanded to fill the 400x400 window, so it's just the frames themselves causing the issue

How do I fix this?

```
`
import tkinter as tk  
import customtkinter as ctk

class Window(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('400x400')
        self.title('Music Mayhem')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        container = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        self.frames={}

        for F in (LoginFrame, RegEmailFrame):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            #frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= 'n'+'e'+'s'+'w')
            frame.pack(expand= True, fill = 'both') 

        self.show_frame(LoginFrame)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() 


#Create a frame to place the logo in
class LogoFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, header_name="Logo Frame", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.logo = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, text='PLACE LOGO HERE')
        self.logo.grid(row=0, column=0) 

#First Frame that will show when app is opened 
class LoginFrame (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, controller, header_name="Login"):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#363635') 
        
        self.logo = LogoFrame(self, header_name='Logo')
        self.logo.grid(row=0, column=0) 
        
        
        self.emailEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=self,
                                 placeholder_text = 'Email Address',
                                 width=150,
                                 height=35)
        self.emailEntry.grid(row=1,column=0, pady = 5)

        self.passwordEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=self,
                                     placeholder_text = 'Password',
                                     width = 150,
                                     height =35)
        self.passwordEntry.grid(row=2, column = 0, pady = 5)

        self.loginBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master = self,
                                      width = 60,
                                      height = 30,
                                      text = 'Login')
        self.loginBtn.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10)

        self.regBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master=self,
                                    width=60,
                                    height=20,
                                    text = 'Register',
                                    fg_color = 'transparent',
                                    command= lambda:
                                    controller.show_frame(RegEmailFrame))
        self.regBtn.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=5)
        

class RegEmailFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,header_name="Register Email"):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#81817e')

        self.logo = LogoFrame(self)
        self.logo.grid(row=0, column=0) 
        
        self.emailLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self,
                                       text='Register Email:')
        self.emailLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
        
        self.emailEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=self,
                                       placeholder_text = 'Email Address',
                                       width=150,
                                       height=35)
        self.emailEntry.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.contBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master=self,
                                     width=60,
                                     height=30,
                                     text = 'Continue')
        self.contBtn.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5)

        self.backBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master=self,
                                    width=60,
                                    height=20,
                                    text = 'Back',
                                    fg_color = 'transparent',
                                    command= lambda:
                                    controller.show_frame(LoginFrame))
        self.backBtn.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=5)
        
        
               
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window()
    app.mainloop() 

`
```

EDIT

I tried to implement forget(). Changes to parts of the code showed below:

```
def show_frame(self, cont, prev):
    prev = self.frames[prev] 
    prev.forget() 
    frame = self.frames[cont] 
    frame.tkraise()

self.regBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master=self,
                            width=60,
                            height=20,
                            text = 'Register',
                            fg_color = 'transparent',
                            command= lambda:
                            controller.show_frame(RegEmailFrame, LoginFrame))

self.backBtn = ctk.CTkButton(master=self,
                                    width=60,
                                    height=20,
                                    text = 'Back',
                                    fg_color = 'transparent',
                                    command= lambda:
                                    controller.show_frame(LoginFrame, RegEmailFrame))
```

However, an error appears :
TypeError: Window.show_frame() missing 1 required positional argument: 'prev'

SOLUTION:

```
    for F in (LoginFrame, RegEmailFrame):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= 'n'+'e'+'s'+'w')
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
```

Comment: You can't fix it with `pack`. Pack is simply not designed for two widgets to occupy the same space. However, you can easily unpack one widget before packing another in its place.

Comment: @BryanOakley so before moving on to the next frame, the current frame has to be destroyed/forgot?

Comment: @BryanOakley I based my code of this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/ . Is there a reason as to why pack can be used here?

Comment: Like I said earlier, with `pack` it is not possible to have two widgets be in the same space at the same time. `grid` and `place` do not have this limitation. With `pack` you'll have to add only one widget at a time, and remove it before switching to another.